# Validate only fields that are visible

Tags: javascript, php

I am using a Radio button for a Condominium and Room option. I have a specific fields for both. How do I validate only fields that are visible and do not validate fields that are hidden?

```
<div id="condo_display" style="display:none">
     <input type="text" name="condo_name" required>
</div

<div id="room_display" style="display:none">
     <input type="text" name="room_name" required>
</div


function propertyType() {

    if (document.getElementById('condo').checked) {
        document.getElementById('condo_display').style.display = 'block';
    } else document.getElementById('condo_display').style.display = 'none';

    if (document.getElementById('room').checked) {
        document.getElementById('room_display').style.display = 'block';
    } else document.getElementById('room_display').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Not clear why you have labelled this jquery unless you are maybe looking for the simplest solution and jquery could provide it. Answer is the jquery visible selector. See https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/.

Comment: You could disable your inputs by default, and remove the disable attribute once you make them visible. This way only the enabled inputs will be submitted.

Comment: My point is how do I validate fields only that is visible because if I choose one then the other div would be hidden and it is a required field. How do I validate fields that are only visible and disregard fields that are hidden.

Comment: How can you toggle when the parent element is hidden?

Comment: `       <input type="radio" name="property_type" value="Condominium" onclick="javascript:propertyType();" id="condo">
        <input type="radio" name="property_type" value="Room" onclick="javascript:propertyType();" id="room">` radio button sir

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] instead of pasting code into comments

Answer (score 0):

Take hidden field that contain action of radio button on change(if click on item one >> 'x', item >>'y') and check it in jquery required filed.

I have demonstrated in below example.
you have two type of option ,check according to your requirement.

```
field_name:{required: function(element) {
                  if($("#is_display").val() == 'y'){         
                            return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                   }
        }
```

if return true than jquery check field for validate else not.
check with above i hope will help you.

Comment: `         <input type="radio" name="property_type" value="Condominium" onclick="javascript:propertyType();" id="condo">
   <input type="radio" name="property_type" value="Room" onclick="javascript:propertyType();" id="room">`

Comment: How do i do it?

Comment: just need to check radio button checked value. if checked value is "Condominium" than it validate that part else return false you need to right all validation with additional radio button check condition.